# UITableView with shadow and corner radius (movie example attached)

Tags: ios, uitableview, calayer

I have a UIViewController with a UITableView. The sits inside the view controller's view with some padding on all sides. I am trying to draw a drop shadow from the table view as well as rounded corners, but I am unable to achieve both at the same time. I have tried with the following code and turned masksToBounds on and off, but setting it to NO create a really weird effect with the shadow scrolling and the calls are not clipping inside the table.

```
[self.tableView.layer setShadowColor:[UIColor blackColor].CGColor];
[self.tableView.layer setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0, 3)];
[self.tableView.layer setShadowOpacity:0.4];
[self.tableView.layer setShadowRadius:3.0f];
[self.tableView.layer setCornerRadius:5.0f];
[self.tableView.layer setShadowPath:[[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.tableView.bounds cornerRadius:5.0f] CGPath]];
```

I am just drawing a UITableView with plain style too. The effect I am trying to achieve can be seen in the free app [Transit App](http://gettransitapp.com) and here's a [movie](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/5445727/ExampleUITableView.mov) where you can see the shadow stays and the table even has a mask that scrolls up and down.

I have searched and searched and haven't been able to put together a solution based on other SO answers or online articles. Help appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Try the below links, some of them are old but you can get some pointer.

[Custom Table Effects](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html)

[Dropshadow 2](http://www.touchthatfruit.com/uitableview-shadows)

[Cool Table Views](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/08/adding-shadow-effects-to-uitableview.html)

[DropShadow](http://rowboatrevolution.com/2009/06/drop-shadows-in-uitableview/)

Okay!! I attempted once again and got an effect, it is again a work around only (instead of using images), the below is what i tried

Create a CALayer, with the same frame as your tableview, give the same curve and all, add the table view on top of this layer, thats it.

```
CALayer *sublayer = [CALayer layer];
sublayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor; // If you dont give this, shadow will not come, dont know why
sublayer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 3);
sublayer.shadowRadius = 5.0;
sublayer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
sublayer.shadowOpacity = 1.0;
sublayer.cornerRadius = 5.0;
sublayer.frame = CGRectMake(myTable.frame.origin.x, myTable.frame.origin.y, myTable.frame.size.width, myTable.frame.size.height);
[self.view.layer addSublayer:sublayer];

[self.view.layer addSublayer:myTable.layer];
```

Ah!! due to some reason I am unable to upload the screenshot from my machine, firewall ;-). I will try from my home.

[image]

-anoop

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately not of these examples are useful for me in my case.

Comment: Did the first link gave you the effect that you wanted? Did you run the sample code?..I was able to see the shadows on all sides of the table.I just went through his project and found that he has all images with a shadow which he uses for the cell and it is nicely done also. Is there something more that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: No the first example is for shadow around each cells. What I am trying to achieve is the entire table with rounded corners and shadow. The cells are then masked inside the table's frame.

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to use images for drop shadows with large tableviews, all that drawing has the ability to slow down performance, which can result in bad user experience, just a word of advice

Comment: The shadows are static outside of the table, so it should not affect the drawing much, since the cells do not have the shadow.

Comment: i'd still keep an eye on your scrolling performance tho. just some advice

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a rather old question, but I recently had the same problem and the solutions here were good examples, but not full enough. So here it is the method I'm using to create shadow of a table view. It can be used also for any other view.

```
-(void)makeShadowToView:(UIView*) view withHeight:(CGFloat)shadowHeight
{
    CGRect bounds = view.frame;
    bounds.size.height = shadowHeight;
    view.clipsToBounds = NO; // Without this row it doesn't display any shadow, at least for a table view
    view.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.9f;
    view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0f, 0.0f);
    view.layer.shadowRadius = 5.0f;
    view.layer.shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:bounds].CGPath;
}
```

Example usage: `[self makeShadowToView:self.view withHeight:height];`
where `height` is added in case you want to recalculate the shadow's height according to the table content's height.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
UITableView * objTableview=[[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, w, h)];

UIView * objViewShadow=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:objTableview.bounds];

objTableview.layer.cornerRadius=5;

// add shadow

objViewShadow.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 3);

objViewShadow.layer.shadowRadius = 5.0;

objViewShadow.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;

objViewShadow.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8;

[objViewShadow addSubview:objTableview];

[self.view addSubview:objViewShadow];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(void)shadowForView{
CALayer *layer = self.viewActionMenu.layer;
layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(-2, 0);
layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
layer.shadowRadius = 2.0f;
layer.shadowOpacity = 0.80f;
// [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.actionView];
                   }
```

And Call:

```
[self shadowForView];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set this two properties

self.tableView.clipsToBounds = NO;

self.tableView.layer.masksToBounds = NO;